# command to synchronize two .bat from vbs

Tags: vbscript, synchronize

I have two bat which are running and I have to wait that "job.bat" is ended off before run "another.bat" because "another.bat" is using a file which comes from "job.bat". Please How to synchronize them within the vbs? Thanks

```
shell.run "job.bat ""my file""" & " " & myVar
'shell.exit
shell.run "another.bat ""lib.txt""" & " " & outVar
```

I used this one between these two shell.run, waiting for file out is available from the first bat but it doesn't change anything

```
  While Not oFSO.FileExists("out") 
   wait 10
   Wend
```

I'm surprised because i had always thought the vbs program is sequential access (sequential instructions), while I was seeing "another.bat" was beeing launched before "job.bat" is terminated!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

You may use the optional boolean parameter `bWaitOnReturn` so that Shell.Run will *wait for the command to complete before continuing execution of the wsh script.*

So, the general syntax of

```
Shell.Run (strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

could in your case look like this:

```
shell.run "job.bat ""my file""" & " " & myVar, , True
'shell.exit
shell.run "another.bat ""lib.txt""" & " " & outVar
```

Answer (score 1):

The execution of your VBS *is* sequential. It's just that by default the `Shell.Run` function doesn't wait for the invoked command/program to finish before going on. It is very likely merely a wrapper around a corresponding system function, possibly [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) or [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) (which you may not need to know), and it's the underlying system function's default behaviour that affects that of VBS's `Shell.Run`.

The best solution in this case would probably be to explicitly specify that the `Run` function should wait for the termination of the first batch file, as per [@PA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762811/297408). Note, though, that you could achieve the same effect if you called the *two* batch files with a *single* `Shell.Run` call, delimiting the two commands with an ampersand (`&`). That is basically like this:

```
Shell.Run "command1 & command2"
```

or, applying to your particular situation, like this:

```
Shell.Run "job.bat ""my file""" & " " & myVar & " & another.bat ""lib.txt""" & " " & outVar
```